# Java: ArrayList^2 to int[][]

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, for-loop

I have this arrayList:

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> temporary = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Some how I need to convert it to a int[][]

I have some sort of loop right?

```
               for(ArrayList<Integer> item: temporary) {
                    //Here??

                }
```

Cheers!

Im stuck because arrays arent dynamic(or what you call it).

Comment: Nice! Didnt thought about that! So now I have every integer...but arrays arent dynamic, there is no array.add method :(

Comment: @AndroidXTr3meN You're right about arrays, but you can quite easily add to an ArrayList or other List type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
final int N = temporary.size();
int[][] a = new int[N][];
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    final ArrayList<Integer> item = temporary.get(i);
    final int M = item.size();
    a[i] = new int[M];
    for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
        a[i][j] = item.get(j); // assumes no null elements!
    }
}
```

Comment: just as a suggestion (and a sort of indirect question), couldn't you do item.toArray() and pass an Integer array as a parameter instead of the nested for?

Comment: @Gamb - That would work, but then you'd have an `Integer` array, not an `int` array like OP wants. Unfortunately, Java does not have a convenient unbox conversion for arrays of boxed primitives; you'd still be stuck with iterating through the `Integer[]` result.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to make do with an Integer[][] (object wrapper of int) you can do it in a single loop (there is an inner loop, but its hidden from you).

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> temporary = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();              
    Integer[][] integers = new Integer[temporary.size()][];
    int i = 0;
    for(ArrayList<Integer> l : temporary)
    {
        integers[i++] = l.toArray(new Integer[l.size()]);           
    }
```

Comment: OP asked how to generate an `int[][]`, not an `Integer[][]`.